# LM hash, hashing a pasword longer then 14 characters

Tags: hash

if there is a password longer then 14 characters, how would LM hash the characters after the 14th and how would it combine it with the hashing from the first 14 characters?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: LM hash is compromised and should not be used anymore.*

LM hash [does not support strings longer than 14 characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LM_hash#cite_note-3). If you are going to use the algorithm internally only and do not need compatibility with other systems, you could for example compute separate hashes for each 14 byte block and `xor` them together.

Comment: tnx, that makes some sense!